# How do I include different types in an array of structs?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm writing a program that uses a lookup table to call a function or return a constant based on a match with its name. Each element in the table is defined by a **tbl_entry_t** struct:

```
typedef int (*fn_ptr_type)(int);

typedef struct {
  char *str;
  union {
    fn_ptr_type fptr;
    int number;
  };
} tbl_entry_t;
```

For example, here's a sample small table:

```
int squareFun (int x) { return x * x; }
int cubeFun (int x) { return x * x * x; }
int Hundred = 100;

char string0[] = "square";
char string1[] = "cube";
char string2[] = "hundred";

tbl_entry_t lookup_table[] = {
  { string0, squareFun },
  { string1, cubeFun },
  { string2, Hundred }
};
```

I want to mix **fn_ptr_type** and **int** values in the table, and I included a **union** in the **struct** to try and achieve this, but I still get a compiler warning:

```
{ string2, Hundred }
warning: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'fn_ptr_type {aka int (*)(int)}'
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: how its related to C++ ? its a classic `C` question. tags fixed

Comment: `{ string2, Hundred }` So, how would you know, you have to use `number` instead of `fptr`? This lookup table makes little sense to me.

Comment: "how its related to C++" By the fact the best answer might require C++?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the union item you want to initialise - otherwise it defaults to initialsing the first item:

```cpp
tbl_entry_t lookup_table[] = {
  { string0, squareFun },
  { string1, cubeFun },
  { string2, .number = Hundred }  // like this
};
```

live eg: https://godbolt.org/z/9WobrG

Answer (score 2):

@code_fodder's answer is what I was looking for, but unfortunately on my compiler, GCC, this gives the error:

```
  { string2, .number = Hundred }
sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
```

However, I've found an ugly workaround that is accepted, and avoids the warning, which is to write:

```
tbl_entry_t lookup_table[] = {
  { string0, squareFun },
  { string1, cubeFun },
  { string2, (fn_ptr_type)Hundred }  // workaround
};
```

Comment: `non-trivial designated initializers not supported` Compile your code with C compiler, not with C++ compiler.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? - I assume its quite old?

Comment: this appears to work from gcc (c-compilation) from version 8.1 onwards: https://godbolt.org/z/so8PWK

Comment: I'm using avr-gcc version 7.3.0.

Comment: @johnsondavies....ah, if you updated one version to 8.1 then you would not have to use your horrible hack - but, if it works ... : )